# dsbulk unload is failing on large table

Tags: cassandra, dsbulk

trying to unload data from a huge table, below is the command used and output.

$ /home/cassandra/dsbulk-1.8.0/bin/dsbulk unload --driver.auth.provider PlainTextAuthProvider --driver.auth.username xxxx  --driver.auth.password xxxx --datastax-java-driver.basic.contact-points 123.123.123.123 -query "select count(*) from sometable with where on clustering column and partial pk -- allow filtering"  --connector.name json --driver.protocol.compression LZ4 --connector.json.mode MULTI_DOCUMENT -maxConcurrentFiles 1 -maxRecords -1 -url dsbulk --executor.continuousPaging.enabled false --executor.maxpersecond 2500 --driver.socket.timeout 240000

```
Setting dsbulk.driver.protocol.compression is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; please configure the driver directly using --datastax-java-driver.advanced.protocol.compression instead.
Setting dsbulk.driver.auth.* is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; please configure the driver directly using --datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.* instead.
Operation directory: /home/cassandra/logs/COUNT_20210423-070104-108326
total | failed | rows/s |      p50ms |      p99ms |     p999ms
    1 |      1 |      0 | 109,790.10 | 110,058.54 | 110,058.54
Operation COUNT_20210423-070104-108326 completed with 1 errors in 1 minute and 50 seconds.
```

Here are the dsbulk records --

```
cassandra@somehost> cd logs
cassandra@somehost> cd COUNT_20210423-070104-108326/
cassandra@somehost> ls
operation.log  unload-errors.log
cassandra@somehost> cat operation.log
2021-04-23 07:01:04 WARN  Setting dsbulk.driver.protocol.compression is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; please configure the driver directly using --datastax-java-driver.advanced.protocol.compression instead.
2021-04-23 07:01:04 WARN  Setting dsbulk.driver.auth.* is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; please configure the driver directly using --datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.* instead.
2021-04-23 07:01:04 INFO  Operation directory: /home/cassandra/logs/COUNT_20210423-070104-108326
2021-04-23 07:02:55 WARN  Operation COUNT_20210423-070104-108326 completed with 1 errors in 1 minute and 50 seconds.
2021-04-23 07:02:55 INFO  Records: total: 1, successful: 0, failed: 1
2021-04-23 07:02:55 INFO  Memory usage: used: 212 MB, free: 1,922 MB, allocated: 2,135 MB, available: 27,305 MB, total gc count: 4, total gc time: 98 ms
2021-04-23 07:02:55 INFO  Reads: total: 1, successful: 0, failed: 1, in-flight: 0
2021-04-23 07:02:55 INFO  Throughput: 0 reads/second
2021-04-23 07:02:55 INFO  Latencies: mean 109,790.10, 75p 110,058.54, 99p 110,058.54, 999p 110,058.54 milliseconds
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Final stats:
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Records: total: 1, successful: 0, failed: 1
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Memory usage: used: 251 MB, free: 1,883 MB, allocated: 2,135 MB, available: 27,305 MB, total gc count: 4, total gc time: 98 ms
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Reads: total: 1, successful: 0, failed: 1, in-flight: 0
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Throughput: 0 reads/second
2021-04-23 07:02:58 INFO  Latencies: mean 109,790.10, 75p 110,058.54, 99p 110,058.54, 999p 110,058.54 milliseconds

cassandra@somehost> cat unload-errors.log
Statement: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultBoundStatement@1083fef9 [0 values, idempotence: <UNSET>, CL: <UNSET>, serial CL: <UNSET>, timestamp: <UNSET>, timeout: <UNSET>]
SELECT batch_id from .... allow filtering (Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded))
        at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.executor.api.subscription.ResultSubscription.toErrorPage(ResultSubscription.java:534)
        at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.executor.api.subscription.ResultSubscription.lambda$fetchNextPage$1(ResultSubscription.java:372)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.setFinalError(CqlRequestHandler.java:447) [4 skipped]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.access$700(CqlRequestHandler.java:94)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler$NodeResponseCallback.processRetryVerdict(CqlRequestHandler.java:859)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler$NodeResponseCallback.processErrorResponse(CqlRequestHandler.java:828)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler$NodeResponseCallback.onResponse(CqlRequestHandler.java:655)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.InFlightHandler.channelRead(InFlightHandler.java:257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [24 skipped]
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
```

Cassandra's system.log snippet ----

```
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2021-04-23 00:01:48,539  MonitoringTask.java:152 - 1 operations timed out in the last 5015 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM my query being run with limit - LIMIT 5000>, total time 10004 msec, timeout 10000 msec/cross-node
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2021-04-23 00:02:38,540  MessagingService.java:1302 - RANGE_SLICE messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 1 cross node
. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 10299 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2021-04-23 00:02:38,551  StatusLogger.java:114 -
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
ReadStage                         1         0     1736872997         0                 0
ContinuousPagingStage             0         0            586         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0     1483193130         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0        9079516         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
MutationStage                     0         0      351841038         0                 0
ViewMutationStage                 0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0          32961         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0       12034828         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0          68612         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              9         0                 0
AntiCompactionExecutor            0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0       20137208         0                 0
SecondaryIndexManagement          0         0              0         0                 0
HintsDispatcher                   0         0           3798         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              8         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0         338955         0                 0
PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0         0         0          66297         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0         247600         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0          41757         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0         525242         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0         767527         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0      958717934         0                65
CompactionManager                 0         0
MessagingService                n/a       0/0
Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
KeyCache                  104857216                104857600                      all
RowCache                          0                        0                      all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand `select count(*) from sometable with where on clustering column and partial pk -- allow filtering` with an additional condition on the token ranges, like this: `and partial pk token(full_pk) > :start and token(full_pk) <= :end` - in this case, DSBulk will perform many queries against specific token ranges that are sent to multiple nodes, and won't create the load onto the single node as in your case.

Look into the [documentation for -query option](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/schemaOptions.html#schemaOptions__dsbulkSchemaOptionsQuery), and for 4th blog in this series of blog posts about DSBulk, that could provide more information & examples: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Comment: Thanks Alex Ott, when I ran the count or unload, it gives some count unlike before but shows failures. What does it mean, does it mean it got all the records satisfying my conditions or it could not fetch all the records as it ran into errors. Attaching the unload and operation log.  --- Operation directory: /home/cassandra/logs/COUNT_20210427-013849-689227
total | failed | rows/s | p50ms | p99ms | p999ms
3,231 | 19 | 17 | 7,733.92 | 105,226.70 | 120,259.08
Operation COUNT_20210427-013849-689227 completed with 19 errors in 3 minutes and 6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are running an `unload` command in [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) to perform a `SELECT COUNT()` which means it has to do a full table scan to return a single row.

In addition, `ALLOW FILTERING` is not recommended unless you restrict the query to a single partition. In any case, the performance of `ALLOW FILTERING` is very unpredictable even in optimal situations.

I suggest that you instead use the DSBulk `count` command which is optimised for counting rows or partitions in Cassandra. For details, see the [Counting data with DSBulk example](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkCountExamples.html).

There's also additional examples in this [DSBulk Counting blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting) which Alex Ott already linked in his answer. Cheers!